# Output of FindStr to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I want to keep the output of the following command to a variable.

```
corflags ICEConnectDT.dll | findstr "PE"
```

When I tried the following statement, it shows the error **"| was unexpected at this time."**

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('corflags ICEConnectDT.dll | findstr PE') do  echo %%a
```

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the pipe

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('corflags ICEConnectDT.dll ^| findstr PE') do echo %%a
```

Or enclose the entire command string in double quotes (inside the single quotes)

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('"corflags ICEConnectDT.dll | findstr PE"') do echo %%a
```